# White Smoke and Engine Coolant Light

Tags: engine, ford, coolant, smoke

I’ve just been in traffic for around an hour and my engine coolant light came on. As I couldn’t pull over anywhere there’s no way I could turn off my engine for a good amount of time(nightmare). The car then began to smoke from the right side of my bonnet and made a strange noise so I immediately turned engine off(should have just done it in first place - stupid me).

Once I started the car back up again after a few minutes once the smoke had gone, the noise had gone too but engine coolant light remained on.

My coolant is near enough on maximum, does anyone have any idea what this could be so I can prepare myself for the price a garage provides me with tomorrow? ‍♀️

Currently sat on a car park not a clue what to do and around 15 mins from home. Is it safe to drive?

Car is a Ford Fiesta Titanium (2010)

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It sounds as though the smoke was steam pouring out from the radiator relief. I'd suspect the initial problem is either the radiator fans aren't working or thermostat is stuck. As far as driving it home, I'd suggest that's a toss-up. If you can, wait until your car is fully cooled down, then you could try. If the car is moving, the better. While driving it, don't tax it too much, turn the heater up to full blast (yah, I know that sucks), and  keep the car moving. If it starts to overheat again, pull over and shut the car off.